# Need to identify same characters between two columns' value in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have two columns one is code and other one is category

```
Code:  category    
321     3210001    
432     4320001    
5314    5314001    
6310    7480001
```

Based on the above code value is exactly the prefix of category value.
Now I have to write a spark sql query which should provide how many rows are categorized and non categorized

eg: if code and prefix of category values are matching, then it should be categorized else
it is non categorized.

from the above table, 4th row is non-categorized and rest of them are categorized

I am trying to use like, substring, len, case but I am not able to achieve this result.

Could someone please help me out on this?

thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 1):

assumed those columns are string , if not cast them to str by `cast(column as string)` in the same query below :

```
select case when instr(category , code) = 1 
            then 'Categorized' 
            else 'Non Categorized' end
     , count(*) counts
from df 
group by case when instr(category , code) = 1 
              then 'Categorized' 
              else 'Non Categorized' end
```

Comment: Hi @eshirvana, sorry for the late response. Thank you for your answer, I will apply your idea in my real problem. Thanks again for your help.